# firefox kiosk mode : just 3 buttons needed

Tags: firefox, kiosk

I've done the researched but I haven't found anything suitable.

I need firefox to start in so called kiosk mode that would result in :

- fullscreen
- no tabs
- no right click
- back home forward buttons

There are plugins like r-kiosk - can I configure them to display only 3 buttons that I need?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Firefox extension that does just this called Webconverger:

http://webconverger.org/kiosk/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webconverger itself is a complete browser operating system with this "kiosk mode" extension loaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mKiosk firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/mkiosk/). It's a Public Firefox Kiosk Mode with optional Tabs Guides for Access Point. Complete solution. Block downloads/addon, bookmarks, reset kiosk inactivity, retry on errors, restricted interface, show favorites as buttons and more...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10147525)

Comment: @Ryan: Links to a tool or library should include a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and ideally [also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code, as appropriate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605). This appears to at least include specific reasons someone might use it, so it's a valid recommendation, even though the question should of course be closed.